# Don't show duplicated rows SQLITE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

**I have a query like:**

```
SELECT coc.title, inc.name FROM cocktail coc, ingredients inc WHERE coc.id = 1...
```

This query is just an short example

**And the result is:**
Title: Cuba Libre, Ingredient Name: Cola
Title: Cuba Libre, Ingredient Name: Rum
Title: Cuba Libre, Ingredient Name: Limette
*I get 3 times the title because this cocktail has 3 incredients.

If I use the result set like this I get 3 times the title as the headline.*

**But I want:**
Title: Cuba Libre, Ingredient Name: Cola
Ingredient Name: Rum
Ingredient Name: Lime
*I would like to have just one time the title and all ingredients in my result set.*

I there any possibility to do this in one query or do I have to execute another request afterwards just for the ingredients?

Comment: do you want the ingredients in a separate row or in a concatenated list?

Comment: What you have given as an example of what you want, is a result set that has different columns for each row. That can't happen directly in SQLite, you'll need to process the results on the application side.

Comment: Why I got downgrades for my question?  

@bluefeet No matter how, I just want if I call _title_ and _name_ in my result set for example, that I get just one time the title but all ingredients.

Comment: @yves I did not downvote your question, I was just asking a follow-up for clarification.

Comment: @bluefeet sorry, I didn't mean you it was just in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the items in the same row, then you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
select c.c_name, group_concat(i.i_name) ingre
from cocktail c
inner join ingredients i
  on c.id = i.c_id
where c.id = 1
group by c.c_name
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f2c10/4)